# Unable to Implement routing in submodules created within the app module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I am trying to implement routing in sub-modules apart from the routing module created in the app module.

I have created three sub-modules in the app module namely login, home and admin modules and I have created a main routing module in the app folder to navigate between login, home and admin sub-modules

I have also created three components in the home module namely HomeComponent, CreateAlertsComponent and UpdateAlertsComponent and routing module with name routeHome.module.ts to navigate between home components.

I am able to route between the sub-modules using routing-module.ts but I am unable to route between the components created in the home module.

I am getting the error as shown below

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Home/home/Alerts/create-alerts'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Home/home/Alerts/create-alerts'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1765)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1730)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1765)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1730)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Below shown is my directory structure with the sub-modules admin, home, login created.

[image]

Below shown is my directory structure with the components and routeHome.module.ts in **home** sub-module

[image]

Please access my code here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modules-angular?file=app/app.module.ts)

Can any body please help resolve this routing conflicts...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have splitted your app into modules. I would suggest you to use [Angular lazy loading feature Modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules). The feature module in your case `HomeModule`, have to be wired up to the `RoutingModule` so the router knows about it.

Updated your code **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modules-angular-8vhepq?file=app%2Frouting.module.ts)**.

In **`RoutingModule`**, update the routes array with the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'Login/login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path:'Home', loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
  { path:'Admin/admin', component: AdminComponent },
];
```

Notice that the lazy loading syntax uses `loadChildren` followed by a string that is the path to the module, a hash mark or #, and the module’s class name.

Configure the `HomeModule` routes by updating **`RouteHomeModule`** as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { CreateAlertsComponent } from './Alerts/create-alerts/create-alerts.component';
import { UpdateAlertsComponent } from './Alerts/update-alerts/update-alerts.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'Alerts/create-alerts', component: CreateAlertsComponent },
  { path: 'Alerts/update-alerts', component: UpdateAlertsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class RouteHomeModule { }
```

Notice that Lazy loaded modules should use `RouterModule.forChild()` instead of `RouterModule.forRoot()`.

Finally remove `HomeComponent`, `CreateAlertsComponent` and `UpdateAlertsComponent` from `AppModule` declarations as these components are part of `HomeModule` and update `routerLink` in `app.component.html`. In **`AppModule`**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AdminComponent,
  ],
  ...
```

**`app.component.html`**:

```
<button mat-raised-button
  routerLink='Home' 
  routerLinkActive="active">
  Home
</button>
```

Comment: also thanks for spending your valuable time for my question

Comment: @Heena glad to help. :)

Comment: can you please help me with this issue.?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968040/unable-to-load-the-popup-in-angular-using-angular-material

Answer (score 3):

You can use child routes to navigate through your application :

```
{
  path:'Home/home',
  component: HomeComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'Alerts/create-alerts',
      component: CreateAlertsComponent,
    },
  ],
},
```

You can also have a look at https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component to see more examples.

edit : also add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your home.component.html file to render your child component.

Comment: but still I am getting the same error as stated in the question above ..... Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Home/home/Alerts/create-alerts'